# LSI 9207-8i and Samsung 850 PRO TRIM support

Tags: ssd, lsi, trim

A Dell R610 server with LSI 9207-8i HBA card has 6 Samsung 850 PRO SSDs connected to it.

`hdparm` shows TRIM support:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdc | grep -i trim
           *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
```

However executing the Samsung magician software on Ubuntu 14.04 returns the following error:

```
ERROR : This feature is not supported for disks connected to LSI RAID HBA Cards.
```

Neither does the `fstrim` command help:

```
fstrim: /: FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not supported
```

The [compatibility matrix](http://docs.avagotech.com/docs-and-downloads/host-bus-adapters/IT_SAS_Gen_2.5CompatibilityList.pdf) doesn't list the Samsung 850 PRO so should I get another controller that supports this SSD for TRIM to work?

I do not need any hardware RAID capabilities and intend to configure these 6 drives with RAID 10 using `mdadm`.

Answer (score 2):

An LSI/Broadcom 9207-8i supports TRIM only with IT firmware. So you can flash the IT firmware (see LSI/Broadcom downloads for this card) in order to gain TRIM support. However, IT firmware does not support RAID, so you will lose the RAID functionality.